# Using python, how to check only that remote mongo server responds without knowlege of any specific document?

Tags: python, mongodb, sockets

Using only python low level socket, e.g. without PyMongo or MongoEngine, how to check only that remote (on LAN) mongo server responds? e.g. without requiring knowledge of any specific document.
With server running verified by mongos from same client and permissions:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('mongodb://192.168.1.2', 27017))
         ...
sock.close()
```

Expected at least a connection but exception was: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Comment: `sock.connect(('192.168.1.2', 27017))`

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Tolonen answered, the URI was unexpected and only the IP string was needed. To verify mongo server is operational create a db and collection (note the '\x01ok' in response):

```
op_msg = [
    b'\x5D', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', # total message size
    b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', # requestID (can be 0)
                  ...
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.connect(('192.168.1.2', 27017))
    sock.send(b''.join(op_msg))
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    print("bytes: {}".format(data))
    sock.close()
                  ...
bytes: b'-\x00\x00\x00\xcf\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xdd
\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x10n\x00
\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01ok\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00'
```